# Android 5.0.2 x86, not working with wifi

Tags: wi-fi, android-x86

I am trying to install the PC version of Android. I've found many links, but none of these versions work with my wifi. My wifi card is a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG (I have an Asus PC). How do I get Android to work with this card?

Comment: More details about your computer will help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but solved it by using a different wifi interface instead of different versions of Android. I had an Edimax interface that was not compatible, and changed to a TP-Link interface which is working now.

Comment: And how did you change this interface? Please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/105016/edit) and add details so that the reader can benefit from this answer easily.